# Issue with UI after using customized Theme roller in JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have changed the default theme to customized theme. Once I use the customized css file, the text boxes and buttons are displayed twice. And also header size is very small. Whats wrong with code? following is the screen shot,[image]

and my code is as follows,

```
<div data-role="page" id="smsPage">
 <div  data-role="header">
            <h4>
               Login Page
            </h4>

 </div>
         <div data-role="content">
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
              Username: <input name="" id="username" value=""  type="text" data-mini="true"><br>
              Password: <input name="" id="password" value=""  type="password" data-mini="true">
                <br>
               <input id="btnDefaultSMS" type="submit" value="Sign in" data-mini="false">
            </div>
         </div>        
</div>

 </div>
```

CSS:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/SampleApplication.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.2.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/mobileapp.js"></script>
```

Did I make any wrong? any suggestions please.

Comment: Could you include css that is relevant to the problem only? The file paths from your html head doesn't help if, `themes/SampleApplication.min.css1` is your own css page.

Comment: You want me to include themes/SampleApplication.min.css1 ?

Comment: If you want to include the css that is relevant to the problem it would help, or a example of the site we could inspect. The problem is most likely css styles conflicting with each other